# Where to find the website folder in ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, domain, directory, files, find

So someone gave me the task to find where is the website code exist on ubuntu server
when I look at the the index.html file path it is
/var/www/example.com/html

but when I go to /var/www directory I am not able to find example.com folder. Can anyone help In this regard or where to find the website code?

Comment: Check the server configuration. Is Apache running, or Nginx? `ps aux | grep apache` or `ps aux | grep nginx`... from there go into /etc/nginx or /etc/apache2/conf.d/sites-enabled/ and look at the config files.

Comment: it is nginx and in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf I found the path to be /var/www/example.com/html where (example.com just for reference) but when I go to the /var/www directory I do not find any folder with .com or the specified folder.

Comment: Try `sudo nginx -T | grep root`.

Comment: If nginx is a reverse proxy for a backend application, then you need to check that application's configuration. You can search for `proxy_pass` in nginx configuration to check for reverse proxy configuration.

Answer (score -2):

cd  /etc/apache2/sites-available folder and check **DocumentRoot** on default.conf file .
if you are not using default.conf then check other file which is available on /etc/apache2/sites-available folder.

Comment: It has already been established in the comments that apache2 is not even used.

Comment: ok..I didn't  seen  the comment. But on nginx you have to follow same procedure.. you need to check any other conf file except default.conf in path /etc/nginx/conf.d/ .

Comment: I have checked all the conf files but the target specified in them does not exists the web is a next.js app and is running with pm2, is it possible that the example.com folder does not exist and the app is running on cache?